# How to prevent launching app twice with android-beacon-library

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

The app works fine that got the beacon I expected , launching app when app detected beacon in background successfully ,too.

However, I noticed that sometimes launched twice.
I paste the AndroidManifest and Application code below.

```
  <application
    android:name=".KforceApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:icon="@drawable/k_512_v2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".LogoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

public class KforceApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements BootstrapNotifier {
private static Context context;
private static ApplifeCycleHandler applifeCycleHandler;
private final String TAG = "KforceApplication";
private static final long BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD = 1100L;
private static final long BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 1100L;
private static final long FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 30000L;
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private Intent intent;
private MemberDao memberDao;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    KforceApplication.applifeCycleHandler = new ApplifeCycleHandler();

    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(applifeCycleHandler);
    initBeaconService();

}


private void initBeaconService() {
    beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    Log.d(TAG, ".......init beacon");

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));



    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD);
    Region region = new Region("all-region-beacon", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);


}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return context;
}

public static ApplifeCycleHandler getApplifeCycleHandler() {
    return applifeCycleHandler;
}


public static boolean isRunningOnBackground() {
    return applifeCycleHandler.getStartedCount() - applifeCycleHandler.getStoppedCount() == 0;
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
    // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
    // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.


    regionBootstrap.disable();
    memberDao = new MemberDao(context);

    Cursor cursor = memberDao.select();

    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        Intent it = new Intent(context, SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(context, LogoActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }


}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "......... did exit");

}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "......... didDetermineStateForRegion exit");
    Log.d(TAG, "beacon determine state : " + state);
  }


}
```

LogoActivity is the first activity that did nothing significant, just an app logo. 
While intent to MainActivity, the app would occasionally launch again automatically and halt at LogoActivity even I tried to make it singleInstance, it never intent to MainActivity.

[Wrong app activity sequence]
LogoActivity → MainActivity → LogoActivity(launch again) → ...... halt

How should I prevent this, please.

```
public class LogoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private final String TAG = "LogoActivity";
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private int LOCATION_CODE = 5646;
private MemberInfoBean bean;
private SigninParam param;
private long member_id;
private SignApi api;
private TokenParam tokenParam;
private Cursor cursor;
private MemberDao memberDao;
private MemberInfoBean infoBean;
private String accessToken, refreshToken;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(biz.kingdo.k_force.R.layout.activity_logo);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    askPermission();
    netWorkStatus();

}

private void netWorkStatus() {
    ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(LogoActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null && info.isAvailable()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "..... user network normal");
       doRefreshToken();
    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }
}

private void doRefreshToken() {
    memberDao = new MemberDao(this);
    tokenParam = new TokenParam();
    cursor = memberDao.select();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        api = new SignApi(this);

        tokenParam.access_token = cursor.getString(15);
        tokenParam.refresh_token = cursor.getString(16);

        Log.d(TAG,"tokenParam.access_token...." + tokenParam.access_token);
        Log.d(TAG,"tokenParam.refresh_token...." + tokenParam.refresh_token);

        api.refreshToken(tokenParam, new Response.Listener<SigninResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(SigninResult response) {

                    GlobalParameter.getInstance().signinResult = response;
                    accessToken = response.data.access_token;
                    refreshToken = response.data.refresh_token;
                    member_id = response.data.member_id;
                    boolean isNew =false;
                    infoBean = memberDao.findOne(member_id);
                    if(infoBean == null){
                        isNew = true;
                        infoBean = new MemberInfoBean();
                        infoBean.setMember_id(member_id);
                    }

                    infoBean.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                    infoBean.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

                    infoBean.setMember_id(member_id);
                    if (isNew) {
                        memberDao.insertMemberInfo(infoBean);

                    } else {
                        memberDao.updateData(infoBean);
                    }


                Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Log.d(TAG, ".... prepare to Main");
                it.putExtra("member_id", member_id);
                startActivity(it);



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });
    }

    if(cursor.getCount()<1){

        askPermission();
       Log.d(TAG,".... cursor.getcount..." + cursor.getCount());
       Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
       startActivity(it);
    }

}


 */

private void askPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_CODE);

        Log.d(TAG, "not permitted , and request");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "permitted , no request");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                   // doRefreshToken();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }).start();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    Log.d(TAG,"... got request permission ....");

    if (requestCode == LOCATION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, ".....permitted");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                       // doRefreshToken();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in LogoAcativity?

Comment: @TuanNguyen  Thanks your reply , added it below.

Comment: Then you write Log.v("Runnable", "call"); insde run() { } function to check how many times it called.

Comment: It called once and halt at LogoActivity.

Comment: Intent it = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
the new flow is LogoActivity => SignActivity => recall LogoActivity => SignActivity?

Comment: It will skip SignInActivity and sign in without user to input their password if the sql MemberDao contains member data. 
Therefore, SignInActivity would not recalled.

Comment: Furthermore, I checked the logcat show MainActivity is active, it keeps working and getting data while app halt at LogoActivity.